# how to improve unit test rate on angular project?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, code-coverage

If you know the rising way, please let me know.
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "statements" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "branches" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "functions" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "lines" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details

## =============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 52.94% ( 315/595 )
Branches     : 20.75% ( 33/159 )
Functions    : 44.23% ( 69/156 )
Lines        : 50.36% ( 283/562 )

01 07 2021 04:01:30.834:WARN [reporter.coverage-istanbul]: Coverage for statements (52.94%) does not meet global threshold (70%)
01 07 2021 04:01:30.834:WARN [reporter.coverage-istanbul]: Coverage for lines (50.36%) does not meet global threshold (70%)
01 07 2021 04:01:30.834:WARN [reporter.coverage-istanbul]: Coverage for branches (20.75%) does not meet global threshold (70%)
01 07 2021 04:01:30.835:WARN [reporter.coverage-istanbul]: Coverage for functions (44.23%) does not meet global threshold (70%)

Comment: I want to rise test result over 85%
is it possible?

Comment: what is the why rise the test result